# How to access a specific row from web table

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to **select a specific row** having class name as 'topicRow post' from the table given below

**Code on website**

```
<table class="content" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr class="topicTitle">
    <tr class="topicSubTitle">
    <tr class="topicRow post">
    <tr class="topicRow_Alt post_alt">
    <tr class="topicRow post">
    <tr class="topicRow_Alt post_alt">
    <tr id="forum_ctl03_ctl00" class="header2">
    <tr class="post">
    <tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Selenium code**

```
WebElement Webtable=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='content']"));
List<WebElement> TotalRowCount=Webtable.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='content']/tbody/tr[contains(@class,'topicRow post')]"));
System.out.println("No. of Rows in the WebTable: "+TotalRowCount.size());
```

**Problem**

Every time it prints the size of all the rows present in table. Please guide...

Comment: Test the `xpath` in the developer tools, how many results do you get?

Comment: @Guy In developers tools 2 rows are getting highlighted which are present in table and I also want to select the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use thread.sleep()
Here is the code

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
List<WebElement> TotalRowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='content']/tbody/tr[contains(@class,'topicRow post')]")); 

System.out.println("No. of Rows in the WebTable: "+TotalRowCount.size());
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you had already use Webtable to find rows, but you still repeat the xpath portion `"//*[@class='content']"` for Webtable in the Webtable.findElements().

Change your code as below:

```
List<WebElement> TotalRowCount=Webtable.
    findElements(By.xpath(".//tr[contains(@class,'topicRow post')]"));
```

Or change to use `driver.findElements()` with repeated xpath portion:

```
List<WebElement> TotalRowCount=driver.
     findElements(By.xpath("//*
      [@class='content']/tbody/tr[contains(@class,'topicRow post')]"));
```

If above two ways don't work as expected, try below code:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.css("table.content"));
List<WebElement> foundRows = table.findElements(By.css("tr.topicRow.post"));
System.out.println("Found rows count： "+ foundRows.size());
```

Comment: I already tried the 2nd option using driver. When i was running it in debug mode it worked fine but when i was running it normally then same problem exists.Let me try the last option.  Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can give an index, 1 for the first match and 2 for the second

```
Webtable.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='content']/tbody/tr[contains(@class,'topicRow post')][1]"));
```